Why do I get an extra space added to my SQL Server when coding in RStudio?
I have an RShiny app connected to a SQL Server database that lets me update said database. I can update the database in both SQL & RShiny and display these updates in both UI's successfully.
When I try to delete these (stock) updates in SQL Server, they fail as the code adds a hidden space before the part number.
Example: my action button (action1) calls this:
observeEvent(input$action1, {
    sql <- paste("INSERT INTO stockExample VALUES('",input$ti1,"','",input$ti2,"','",input$ti3,"');")
    sqlQuery(dbCon, sql)
    output$adjust1 <- renderText(paste(input$ti3, "of ", input$ti1, " have been added to location ", input$ti2))
})

Which results in this result in SQL line 11:

A clear, unwanted space at q1. Line 12, which is added from SQL, does not include said extra space.
Why is that?
Everything I have tried is all related to the code above and removing any innocuous spaces.

In case you aren't aware, SQL Server 2008 reached end of life over 5 years ago. You urgently need to upgrade to a supported version of the software; using such an outdated version is a significant security concern for you, your employer, and your customers.

Separating terms with a space is expected default behaviour for paste(), you are likely after paste0():
input <- list(ti1 = "A", ti2 = "B", ti3 = "C")

# paste, default sep = " "
paste("INSERT INTO stockExample VALUES('",input$ti1,"','",input$ti2,"','",input$ti3,"');")
#> [1] "INSERT INTO stockExample VALUES(' A ',' B ',' C ');"

# paste0, equiv. of paste(..., sep = "")
paste0("INSERT INTO stockExample VALUES('",input$ti1,"','",input$ti2,"','",input$ti3,"');")
#> [1] "INSERT INTO stockExample VALUES('A','B','C');"

On the other hand, constructing queries from raw user input like this is just playing with fire. Guessing from your previous question you are not trying to keep some legacy RODBC-based project alive but working on a new code, I'd strongly consider switching to DBI and odbc and parametrized queries.

Same : " I'd strongly consider switching to DBI and odbc". Done for years.
